# Jekyll offline docs return invalid command

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I install `jekyll-docs` on windows using `gem install jekyll-docs`

it returns:

```
Successfully installed jekyll-docs-3.0.1
Parsing documentation for jekyll-docs-3.0.1
Installing ri documentation for jekyll-docs-3.0.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `intern' for []:Array
```

then I run `jekyll docs`then it returns:

```
Invalid command. Use --help for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a ruby install problem.

To get around this you can try `gem install jekyll-docs --no-rdoc --no-ri`

Comment: could you tell me what exactly the problem?